# dplyr mutate function to evaluate values within columns (current, previous, next) vertically

Tags: r, dplyr

I have scoured SO for a way to achieve what I need without luck so here it goes.
A while back I discovered the package dplyr and its potential. I am thinking this package can do what I want, I just don't know how. This is a small subset of my data, but should be representative of my problem.

```
    dummy<-structure(list(time = structure(1:20, .Label = c("2015-03-25 12:24:00", 
    "2015-03-25 21:08:00", "2015-03-25 21:13:00", "2015-03-25 21:47:00", 
    "2015-03-26 03:08:00", "2015-04-01 20:30:00", "2015-04-01 20:34:00", 
    "2015-04-01 20:42:00", "2015-04-01 20:45:00", "2015-09-29 18:26:00", 
    "2015-09-29 19:11:00", "2015-09-29 21:21:00", "2015-09-29 22:03:00", 
    "2015-09-29 22:38:00", "2015-09-30 00:48:00", "2015-09-30 01:38:00", 
    "2015-09-30 01:41:00", "2015-09-30 01:45:00", "2015-09-30 01:47:00", 
    "2015-09-30 01:49:00"), class = "factor"), ID = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), station = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 
    6L, 5, 5, 5L, 7, 7, 7L, 
    7)), .Names = c("time", "ID", "station"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -20L))
```

I wish to evaluate rows within the time column conditional on the ID and station column. Specifically, I would like the function (dplyr?) to evaluate each time row, and compare the time to the previous time (row-1) and next time (row+1). If the time of current row is within 1 hour of time of previous and/or next row, and the ID and station of current row match that of previous and/or next row, then I would like to add in a new row a 1, otherwise a 0.

How would I achieve this using dplyr?

The expected outcome should be like this:

```
                  time ID station new.value
1  2015-03-25 12:24:00  1       1         0
2  2015-03-25 21:08:00  1       1         1
3  2015-03-25 21:13:00  1       1         1
4  2015-03-25 21:47:00  1       2         0
5  2015-03-26 03:08:00  1       3         0
6  2015-04-01 20:30:00  1       4         1
7  2015-04-01 20:34:00  1       4         1
8  2015-04-01 20:42:00  1       4         1
9  2015-04-01 20:45:00  1       4         1
10 2015-09-29 18:26:00  2       5         1
11 2015-09-29 19:11:00  2       5         1
12 2015-09-29 21:21:00  2       6         1
13 2015-09-29 22:03:00  2       6         1
14 2015-09-29 22:38:00  2       5         0
15 2015-09-30 00:48:00  2       5         1
16 2015-09-30 01:38:00  2       5         1
17 2015-09-30 01:41:00  2       7         1
18 2015-09-30 01:45:00  2       7         1
19 2015-09-30 01:47:00  2       7         1
20 2015-09-30 01:49:00  2       7         1
```

Comment: I don't think you need dplyr, I think you just need a couple `diff` operations.  Note that "Class "POSIXct" represents the (signed) number of seconds since the beginning of 1970 (in the UTC time zone) as a numeric vector." so you would want to look for diffs less than 3600 seconds.

Comment: Not sure about `dplyr`, but data.table has rolling joins which seems to address your question in a most efficient way. A recent article describe the feature in details: [Understanding data.table Rolling Joins](http://r-norberg.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/understanding-datatable-rolling-joins.html). To provide an hour to roll just use 60*60 (as POSIXct is number of seconds). This way you should be able to detect those rows using binary merge. If pure performance is not your aim then `shift(x)` or `c(NA, x[-.N])` / `c(x[-1L], NA)` should be enough to create columns to compare with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an option using the `difftime` with `dplyr` mutate function. Firstly, we use a `group_by` operation to make sure the comparison is within each unique combination of ID and Station. The `difftime` can be used to calculate the difference time, here the units will be set as `hours` for convenience. The `lag` and `lead` functions are also from `dplyr` package which shift the selected column backward or forward. Combining with the vectorised operation of difftime, you can calculate the time difference between the current row and the previous/next row. We use `abs` to make sure the result is absolute value. The condition of `<1` make sure the difference is within an hour. `as.integer` convert the logical values (T or F) to (1 or 0) correspondingly.

```
library(dplyr)
dummy %>% group_by(ID, station) %>% 
          mutate(new.value = as.integer(
                 abs(difftime(time, lag(time, default = Inf), units = "hours")) < 1 | 
                 abs(difftime(time, lead(time, default = Inf), units = "hours")) < 1))

Source: local data frame [20 x 4]
Groups: ID, station [7]

                  time    ID station new.value
                (time) (int)   (dbl)     (int)
1  2015-03-25 12:24:00     1       1         0
2  2015-03-25 21:08:00     1       1         1
3  2015-03-25 21:13:00     1       1         1
4  2015-03-25 21:47:00     1       2         0
5  2015-03-26 03:08:00     1       3         0
6  2015-04-01 20:30:00     1       4         1
7  2015-04-01 20:34:00     1       4         1
8  2015-04-01 20:42:00     1       4         1
9  2015-04-01 20:45:00     1       4         1
10 2015-09-29 18:26:00     2       5         1
11 2015-09-29 19:11:00     2       5         1
12 2015-09-29 21:21:00     2       6         1
13 2015-09-29 22:03:00     2       6         1
14 2015-09-29 22:38:00     2       5         0
15 2015-09-30 00:48:00     2       5         1
16 2015-09-30 01:38:00     2       5         1
17 2015-09-30 01:41:00     2       7         1
18 2015-09-30 01:45:00     2       7         1
19 2015-09-30 01:47:00     2       7         1
20 2015-09-30 01:49:00     2       7         1
```

Comment: This is indeed what I am looking for.  Could you please elaborate on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Psidom's answer is great -- here's a `data.table` approach.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dummy)
# you do NOT want a factor for your time variable
dummy[, time := as.POSIXct(time) ]
dummy[, `:=`(lag_diff = c(Inf, diff(as.numeric(time))),
             lead_diff = c(diff(as.numeric(time)), Inf)),
      by = .(ID, station) ]
dummy[, new.value := as.integer(lag_diff < 3600 | lead_diff < 3600) ]
dummy
```

Answer (score 3):

Another solution using R base functions (`sapply` and `difftime`):

```
n=nrow(dummy)
dummy$new.value=
as.numeric(sapply(1:n, function(i) 
(i<n && (dummy[i,"ID"]==dummy[i+1,"ID"] && dummy[i,"station"]==dummy[i+1,"station"]) 
&& abs(as.numeric(difftime(dummy[i,"time"], dummy[i+1,"time"]), "hours"))<=1) 
|| 
(i>1 && (dummy[i,"ID"]==dummy[i-1,"ID"] && dummy[i,"station"]==dummy[i-1,"station"]) 
&& abs(as.numeric(difftime(dummy[i,"time"], dummy[i-1,"time"]), "hours"))<=1) 
))

# > dummy
                  # time ID station new.value
# 1  2015-03-25 12:24:00  1       1         0
# 2  2015-03-25 21:08:00  1       1         1
# 3  2015-03-25 21:13:00  1       1         1
# 4  2015-03-25 21:47:00  1       2         0
# 5  2015-03-26 03:08:00  1       3         0
# 6  2015-04-01 20:30:00  1       4         1
# 7  2015-04-01 20:34:00  1       4         1
# 8  2015-04-01 20:42:00  1       4         1
# 9  2015-04-01 20:45:00  1       4         1
# 10 2015-09-29 18:26:00  2       5         1
# 11 2015-09-29 19:11:00  2       5         1
# 12 2015-09-29 21:21:00  2       6         1
# 13 2015-09-29 22:03:00  2       6         1
# 14 2015-09-29 22:38:00  2       5         0
# 15 2015-09-30 00:48:00  2       5         1
# 16 2015-09-30 01:38:00  2       5         1
# 17 2015-09-30 01:41:00  2       7         1
# 18 2015-09-30 01:45:00  2       7         1
# 19 2015-09-30 01:47:00  2       7         1
# 20 2015-09-30 01:49:00  2       7         1
```